# Gorm can't load uuid from database

Tags: go, mariadb, uuid, go-gorm

Database model:

```
type User struct {
    Id          uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Email       string    `gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
    Username    string    `gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
    Password    string
    Description string
}
```

How I catch uuid:

```
res = db.Table("users").Select("id").Where(
    "username = ?", loginUser.Username,
).Or(
    "email = ?", auth.GenerateSHAHash(loginUser.Username),
).Find(&dbUser.Id)

if res.Error != nil {
    log.Panic(res.Error)
}
```

Error I have:

`sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "id": converting driver.Value type []uint8 ("695c1f41-3d0e-4916-95cc-726a8d403ffc") to a uint8: value out of range`

I can set Id column type to string, but I don't think it will be correct.

Comment: What is the type of column representing Id in database? It looks like in your database `id` is simply number (uint8) while you are trying to serialize slice of uint8 (`uuid.UUID`) into that column.

Comment: It has uuid type in database